# Angular (or angular-rails-resource) is serializing nested data strangely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, serialization

I have an [angular-rails-resource](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource) query that looks like this:

```
    Payment.query({
      between: {
        startDate: moment($scope.startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        endDate: moment($scope.endDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
      }
    }) // irrelevant code omitted
```

Unfortunately my query string is getting formatted like this:

```
/payments?between=%7B%22startDate%22:%222015-02-18%22,%22endDate%22:%222015-03-04%22%7D
```

Which comes through to Rails like this:

```
{"between"=>"{\"startDate\":\"2015-02-18\",\"endDate\":\"2015-03-04\"}"}
```

It's double-escaping the inner attributes. What I of course want is this:

```
{"between"=>{"startDate":"2015-02-18","endDate":"2015-03-04"}}
```

I can't tell if this is an Angular thing or an angular-rails-resource thing. Any suggestions on how to try to get the data to be serialized properly?

Comment: `%7B%22startDate%22:%222015-02-18%22,%22endDate%22:%222015-03-04%22%7D` is single-escaped

Comment: I don't really feel like the `%22`s (backslashes) should be there, you know?

Comment: `%22` is `"`, not backlash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure it out myself. Here's the fix:

```
Payment.query({
  "between[startDate]": moment($scope.startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
  "between[endDate]": moment($scope.endDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
})
```

It doesn't strike me as the greatest conceivable solution but it seems sufficiently non-terrible to me.